# Understanding relationship between the affine combination and line equation.

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVJCh.png)

Let say that I look at the graph above.
I understand that this can be thought of in two ways,

1) Affine combination of two vectors in a vector space: $a \vec{x}+b\vec{y}$, where $\vec{x} = [9,0], \vec{y} = [0,8], a$ and $ b \in \mathbb R$ and $ a + b = 1$

2) Equation of a line: $\frac{2}{3}x + \frac{3}{4}y = 6$.

So, since the graphical representations of the two above are the same, there must be a way of thinking to relate them. However, I could not find a way to do so. Can you please explain how to understand the relationship between the two (affine combination and equation of a line) above?

Comment: These are two different ways to describe the same set. The first tells you how to generate every element directly, while the second describes it as the null set of a particular equation.